# flex - change button text to random xml entry onclick

Tags: xml, apache-flex, random, flash-builder

i have an app i'm making in flex and I'd like to have a button's text change to a random entry within an xml when the button is clicked....the xml is in the assets folder and is titled games.xml. I would like to have a random game be selected when the button is pressed.

here is games.xml

```
<games>
    <game> GameName1
    <description> description1 </description>
    </game>
    <game> GameName2
    <description> description2 </description>
    </game>
    <game> GameName3
    <description> description3 </description>
    </game>
</games>
```

and here is the flex file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    backgroundColor="#0000FF" title="games!">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            gamebutton.label="test"   <---i want this to be a random game name
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Button id="gamebutton" click="button1_clickHandler(event)" horizontalCenter="0" top="10" x="0" width="95%" label="Pick A Game"/>

</s:View>
```

thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: In the final version of the code the games will have different names, not just numerical placeholders. Any way to have it draw from the xml? Sorry i wasnt clear at first

Answer (score 1):

Hi just put the following code in button1_clickHandler

```
protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var num:int = (Math.random() * (4 - 1)) + 1
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    gamebutton.label="GameName" + num.toString();
}
```

here 4 is maximum game + 1 and 1 is munimum.and num will be the random number between 1 to 3.

Have a nice day.

Comment: In the final version of the code the games will have different names, not just numerical placeholders. Any way to have it draw from the xml? Sorry i wasnt clear at first

Comment: you will get the array and you just need to give te index for that with given index number.
Eg. you have array names games and you just need to pass the index that is games[num].... might be this one is the simplest method ever.